# Approximation for the infinite counting decimal

Tags: approximation, real-numbers, fractions, irrational-numbers

Somewhere between the real number range, there exists a 
decimal that 'counts' natural numbers infinitely on its digits as:

$
0.123456789101112131415161718192021.........
$

It goes on 'counting' forever.

It is an irrational number, so

I'd like to find a close approximation of it (for about 30+ digits for example)
like the PI approximation $(22/7)$

One last question for fun:

Is that number has been given a name before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number is called the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) Some of it's approximation is $$\frac{10}{81}=0.\overline{123456790}$$
An even better approximation is
$$\frac{60499999499}{490050000000}$$

Comment: Very quickly answered. Thank you!